# Error when creating a panel dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a panel in order to fill it up with some controls but i got error when i try to write its properties.

My code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

      Panel pbx;
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a Dynamic Panel
            pbx = new Panel();
            pbx.ID = "pbx";
            pbx.BorderWidth = 1;
            pbx.Width = 300;
            this.form1.Controls.Add(pbx);
        }

//some other functions
}
```

Visual Studio 2012 underlines "ID", "BorderWidth" and "Width" words, so i cant run the project. one of errors is like this:

> 'simplePanel.Panel' does not contain a definition for 'BorderWidth'
>   and no extension method 'BorderWidth' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'simplePanel.Panel' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

edit: I can create a textbox or label with no problem. But not a panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a class called `simplePanel.Panel` which conflicts with `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel` (which I assume is what you are trying to reference). If your `_Default` class is in the `simplePanel` namespace as well, then you need to fully qualify the references to `Panel` so that the compiler knows which one you mean:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel pbx;
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a Dynamic Panel
        pbx = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel();
```

Comment: that didn't work. i paste your code at the top but nothing changed.

Comment: @AliSağırvelioğulları: Is your `_Default` class inside a `namespace`, or is `public partial class _Default` really the first line in the file?

Comment: it's in simplePanel namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width like this:

```
pbx.Width = new Unit("300px");
```

It will help you out to cover the situation.